# How to forbid that Authentication Required windows?

Tags: windows, dialog-window

As the Great Firewall,I am hard to access *Stack Exchange*,So I use **VPN**.I'm in *11.1*.Everytime I open *Mathemtica*,this windows will pop up when I open my VPN,

[image]

But when I close the VPN it will disappear.It will not happen when I'm in *11.0*.Any method can forbid it?

Comment: That seems mildly annoying.

Comment: @user6014 Do you also suffer this?

Comment: You might want to mention that you're behind the Great Firewall...

Comment: @yode I do not. It's attempting to contact Wolfracloud.com/something. Do you use your cloud account from Mathematica?

Comment: I just have one account,what meaning of your `cloud account`?